# How to copy an eclipse project without svn info

Tags: eclipse, svn

I would like to create a copy of an svn-controlled project in eclipse, but without the svn metadata. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: donot know exactly but i think there should be hidden .svn folders delete them and it is done

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) command.

Comment: Beautiful. Wish I had asked earlier.

Comment: There's usually an export option in most svn GUI's too.

Answer (score 5):

1. Import project into workspace
2. Right click on project -> Team -> Disconnect
3. Select "Also delete the SVN meta information from the file system."

Your project is now disconnected with no SVN meta information on your local file system. You can copy paste all files needed.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to copy your folder from one project into another, in the Project Explorer:

1. Right-click the folder you want to copy.
2. Select "Team -> Copy To".
3. Choose your destination folder in the dialogue box.
4. Click the radiobutton "Copy resources without SVN history".
5. Click OK

You should see the folder in the new location.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you do not want to use svn export:
Copy the Project folder as usual. 
Then run the following from project's directory :

```
find . -name ".svn" | xargs rm -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and then run the following from project's directory :

```
find . -name '.svn' -exec rm -r {} \;
```